# How can I find the buffer of CryptGenRandom?

Tags: ida, disassembly, windows, binary-analysis, ghidra

I am trying to analyze the [CryptGenRandom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) algorithm on my Windows 10 laptop.

According to Niels Ferguson's [Whitepaper](https://aka.ms/win10rng) called 'The Windows 10 random number generation infrastructure', the CryptGenRandom algorithm uses a buffer for small requests:

> All PRNGs in the system are SP800-90 `AES_CTR_DRBG` with 256-bit security strength using the `df()` function for seeding and re-seeding (see SP 800-90 for details). (…) The Basic PRNGs are not used directly, but rather through a wrapping layer that adds several features.
>
> - A small buffer of random bytes to improve performance for small requests.
> - A lock to support multi-threading.
> - `A` seed version.
>
> (…) The buffering is straightforward. There is a small buffer (currently 128 bytes). If a request for random bytes is 128 bytes or larger, it is generated directly from `AES_CTR_DRGB`. If it is smaller than 128 bytes it is taken from the buffer. The buffer is re-filled from the `AES_CTR_DRBG` whenever it runs empty. So, if the buffer contains 4 bytes and the request is for 8 bytes, the 4 bytes are taken from the buffer, the buffer is refilled with 128 bytes, and the first 4 bytes of the refilled buffer are used to complete the request, leaving 124 bytes in the buffer.

I would like to know if it is possible to locate and access this buffer.

To achieve this, I located the `Advapi32.dll` file in my windows/system32 folder. The `CryptGenRandom` algorithm is defined in this file. I decompiled this file with Ghidra. However, I am very unexperienced with Ghidra and did not manage to find the buffer. Below you can see the entry function with renamed parameters:

```c
    /* WARNING: Function: _guard_dispatch_icall replaced with injection: guard_dispatch_icall */
    /* WARNING: Globals starting with '_' overlap smaller symbols at the same address */
    
    ulonglong entry(undefined8 hProv,int dwLen,longlong pbBuffer)
    
    {
      byte bVar1;
      int iVar2;
      undefined4 extraout_var;
      uint *puVar3;
      undefined1 *puVar4;
      uint uVar5;
      uint *puVar6;
      uint uVar7;
      
      if (dwLen == 1) {
        FUN_18001d464(hProv,1);
      }
      uVar7 = 0;
      if (dwLen == 1) {
        uVar5 = 0;
        puVar4 = &DAT_1800a1008;
        do {
          iVar2 = RtlInitializeCriticalSection(*(undefined8 *)(puVar4 + -8));
          if (iVar2 < 0) {
            iVar2 = FUN_180015850();
            return CONCAT44(extraout_var,iVar2) & 0xffffffffffffff00;
          }
          *puVar4 = 1;
          uVar5 = uVar5 + 1;
          puVar4 = puVar4 + 0x10;
        } while (uVar5 < 4);
        _DAT_1800a44d4 = 1;
      }
      uVar5 = 1 << ((byte)dwLen & 0x1f);
      puVar6 = &DAT_1800a43c8;
      bVar1 = 1;
      puVar3 = &DAT_18006a738;
      do {
        if (((*puVar3 & uVar5) != 0) &&
           ((dwLen != 0 || (((*puVar6 & 2) != 0 && ((pbBuffer == 0 || ((int)*puVar3 < 0)))))))) {
          bVar1 = (**(code **)(puVar3 + -2))(hProv,dwLen,pbBuffer);
          if (bVar1 == 0) goto LAB_18002d198;
          (&DAT_1800a43c8)[(int)uVar7] = *puVar6 | uVar5;
        }
        uVar7 = uVar7 + 1;
        puVar3 = puVar3 + 4;
        puVar6 = puVar6 + 1;
      } while (uVar7 < 8);
      if (bVar1 == 0) {
    LAB_18002d198:
        if (dwLen != 1) goto LAB_18001577c;
      }
      else {
    LAB_18001577c:
        if ((dwLen != 0) || (pbBuffer != 0)) goto LAB_180015785;
      }
      FUN_180015850();
    LAB_180015785:
      return (ulonglong)bVar1;
    }
```

Since `dwLen` is the number of requested bytes, I would expect there to be a statement that checks whether this number is at most the number of available random bytes in the buffer. But I see no such statement. Also, `pbBuffer` is a different buffer than the one I am looking for.

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a ghidra answer but done using windbg
Assuming You Have Code as below

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")
void hexdump(byte *inbuf, DWORD count)
{
    DWORD j = 0;
    while (j < count)
    {
        for (DWORD i = j; i < j + 16; i++)
        {
            printf("%02x ", inbuf[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        j = j + 16;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv = NULL;
    byte buff[0x200] = {0};
    DWORD count = 0x30;
    BOOL res = CryptAcquireContextA(&hCryptProv, "MyKeyContainer", NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0);
    if (res)
    {
        res = CryptGenRandom(hCryptProv, count, buff);
        if (res)
        {
            hexdump(buff, count);
        }
    }
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0);
}
```

you can employ memory Breakpoint to find who is writing to your buffer and just corelate with your ghidra/ida disassembly.

the buffers are Actually Created in Heap and the pointers to them are Written in
bcryptprimitives!g_AesStatesTable

```
0:000> lsa .
    21:     DWORD count = 0x30;
    22:     BOOL res = CryptAcquireContextA(&hCryptProv, "MyKeyContainer", NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0);
    23:     if (res)
    24:     {
>   25:         res = CryptGenRandom(hCryptProv, count, buff); <--------------
    26:         if (res)
    27:         {
    28:             hexdump(buff, count);
    29:         }
    30:     }
0:000> ba w1 buff
0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
ntdll!memcpy+0x144:
00007ffe`988d4044 0f100411        movups  xmm0,xmmword ptr [rcx+rdx] ds:0000027d`a4dbc500=25fc4b9c5d3ddad46e5610a21eff9e1f
0:000> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 000000d0`1b6ff648 00007ffe`96815400 ntdll!memcpy+0x144
01 000000d0`1b6ff650 00007ffe`9681513c bcryptprimitives!AesRNGState_generate+0x190
02 000000d0`1b6ff700 00007ffe`9586101d bcryptprimitives!ProcessPrng+0x12c
03 000000d0`1b6ff7b0 00007ffe`94f054f7 CRYPTBASE!SystemFunction036+0xd
04 000000d0`1b6ff7e0 00007ffe`958416b2 rsaenh!CPGenRandom+0x27
05 000000d0`1b6ff810 00007ff6`f72a110f CRYPTSP!CryptGenRandom+0x42
06 000000d0`1b6ff840 00007ff6`f72a14d4 crypt!main+0x7f [crypt.cpp @ 25] <-----------
07 (Inline Function) --------`-------- crypt!invoke_main+0x22 
08 000000d0`1b6ffaa0 00007ffe`968a7614 crypt!__scrt_common_main_seh+0x10c 
09 000000d0`1b6ffae0 00007ffe`988826f1 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
0a 000000d0`1b6ffb10 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
0:000> ub . 
ntdll!memcpy+0x126:
00007ffe`988d4026 0f2959e0        movaps  xmmword ptr [rcx-20h],xmm3
00007ffe`988d402a 0f28c4          movaps  xmm0,xmm4
00007ffe`988d402d 75d1            jne     ntdll!memcpy+0x100 (00007ffe`988d4000)
00007ffe`988d402f 4d8bc8          mov     r9,r8
00007ffe`988d4032 49c1e904        shr     r9,4
00007ffe`988d4036 7419            je      ntdll!memcpy+0x151 (00007ffe`988d4051)
00007ffe`988d4038 0f1f840000000000 nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
00007ffe`988d4040 0f2941f0        movaps  xmmword ptr [rcx-10h],xmm0 <------------- 
this triggered the write breakpoint
0:000> r rcx
rcx=000000d01b6ff890
0:000> ? xmm0
Evaluate expression: 5380964661682152702 = 4aad06d9`a87ea4fe <----------- 
this is being copied from api buffer to codes buff

0:000> db bcryptprimitives!g_AesStatesTable l2
00007ffe`9687b8e0  60 c0 db a4 7d 02 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  `...}...........

0:000> db poi(bcryptprimitives!g_AesStatesTable) l4
0000027d`a4dbc060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0000027d`a4dbc070  f0 c3 db a4 7d 02 00 00-90 c2 db a4 7d 02 00 00  ....}.......}...

0:000> db poi(poi(bcryptprimitives!g_AesStatesTable)+10) l120
0000027d`a4dbc3f0  30 01 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  0...............
0000027d`a4dbc400  dd 1e e5 f2 c9 ec e9 b5-70 2e 3b c6 da e1 f9 59  ........p.;....Y
0000027d`a4dbc410  f7 7d 2c 07 2d 57 ae e0-c8 5c 31 05 08 9a 10 9f  .},.-W...\1.....
0000027d`a4dbc420  bc 83 0c 3b 8f 11 ee 03-b0 8a 9a 7e 0e f5 c5 cd  ...;.......~....
0000027d`a4dbc430  da 4f 77 48 92 54 98 57-12 17 ed 2b af 97 1e 88  .OwH.T.W...+.... <-------
0000027d`a4dbc440  03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0000027d`a4dbc450  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0000027d`a4dbc460  80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-39 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........9.......
0000027d`a4dbc470  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff-fe ff ff ff 01 00 00 00  ................
0000027d`a4dbc480  c8 2d 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .-..............
0000027d`a4dbc490  d0 07 00 02 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0000027d`a4dbc4a0  01 20 b5 34 61 da 46 2a-20 ab 63 2a 90 28 cb 36  . .4a.F* .c*.(.6
0000027d`a4dbc4b0  51 4a dc 28 50 b5 a4 97-78 b8 13 33 e3 3c 5a 24  QJ.(P...x..3.<Z$
0000027d`a4dbc4c0  e4 6c 8d 70 7a 19 5d 5e-71 15 78 95 4b 9b 61 f2  .l.pz.]^q.x.K.a.
0000027d`a4dbc4d0  0f 8e 0d 32 5b 39 1a 53-6b 2a 0e 47 ae e1 2a 47  ...2[9.Sk*.G..*G
0000027d`a4dbc4e0  37 d4 d7 78 01 de 34 d8-f4 27 fe bf fb 2b 07 7a  7..x..4..'...+.z
0000027d`a4dbc4f0  fe a4 7e a8 d9 06 ad 4a-4a 70 8a c3 57 53 54 e9  ..~....JJp..WST. <-------
0000027d`a4dbc500  1f 9e ff 1e a2 10 56 6e-d4 da 3d 5d 9c 4b fc 25  ......Vn..=].K.% <--------
```

you need to catch this buffer before it is wiped off after memcpy
using SymCryptWipeAsm

```
0:000> db buff
000000d0`1b6ff880  fe a4 7e a8 d9 06 ad 4a-4a 70 8a c3 57 53 54 e9  ..~....JJp..WST.
000000d0`1b6ff890  1f 9e ff 1e a2 10 56 6e-d4 da 3d 5d 9c 4b fc 25  ......Vn..=].K.%
000000d0`1b6ff8a0  da 4f 77 48 92 54 98 57-12 17 ed 2b af 97 1e 88  .OwH.T.W...+....
000000d0`1b6ff8b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000d0`1b6ff8c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000d0`1b6ff8d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000d0`1b6ff8e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000d0`1b6ff8f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

the pertinent disassembly / decompilation in ghidra is as follows

```
in bool AesRNGState_generate(byte *param_1,byte *buff,dword dwLen)

 if (uVar10 < 0x80) {
    uVar2 = *(ulonglong *)(param_1 + 0x70);
    puVar1 = (ulonglong *)(param_1 + 0x70);
    uVar9 = uVar10;
    if (uVar2 != 0) {
      if (uVar2 <= uVar10) {
        uVar9 = uVar2;
      }
      memcpy(local_80,param_1 + (uVar2 - uVar9) + 0xb0,uVar9);
      SymCryptWipeAsm(param_1 + ((*puVar1 + 0xb0) - uVar9),(dword)uVar9);
      *puVar1 = *puVar1 - uVar9;
      local_80 = pbVar8 + uVar9;
      uVar9 = uVar10 - uVar9;
    }
    if (uVar9 != 0) {
      SymCryptRngAesGenerate(param_1 + 0x10,param_1 + 0xb0,0x80);
      *puVar1 = 0x80;
      memcpy(local_80,param_1 + (0x130 - uVar9),uVar9);
      SymCryptWipeAsm(param_1 + ((*puVar1 + 0xb0) - uVar9),(dword)uVar9);
      *puVar1 = ~(ulonglong)((uint)((uVar10 - 1 ^ uVar10) >> 1) & 0xf) & *puVar1 - uVar9;
    }
  }
  else {
    SymCryptRngAesGenerate(param_1 + 0x10,buff,dwLen);
  }
```

Comment: In my Ghidra decompiler, the function AesRNGState_generate is not defined and probably is one of the FUN_1800 functions. How can I change this and find out which one is the actual function?

Comment: And I can not open `Bcryptprimitives.dll` in Ida at all, but firstly I could… I don’t know what changed

Comment: However, that doesn't matter if I can access the buffer with windbg as you specified

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple exercise in following the stubs/imports in different DLLs.
This is the flow that I see

```
CRYPTSP!CryptGenRandom -> rsaenh!CPGenRandom -> CRYPTBASE!SystemFunction036(on my machine atleast) -> bcryptPrimitives!ProcessPrng
```

`bcryptPrimitives!ProcessPrng` has the most code. On opening this with any disassembler of choice we can see that `AesRNGState_generate` is called and additionally involves `g_AesStatesTable`/`g_rootAesRngState` and further eventually `bcryptPrimitives!SymCryptRngAesReseed` is called which looks like.

```c
__int64 __fastcall SymCryptRngAesReseed(__int64 a1, void *a2, size_t a3)
{
  __int64 result; // rax
  __int64 v5[6]; // [rsp+20h] [rbp-48h] BYREF

  if ( a3 - 32 > 0x20 )
    return 209715368i64;
  SymCryptRngAesDf(a2, a3);
  SymCryptRngAesUpdate(a1, v5, 0i64);
  result = 0i64;
  *(_QWORD *)(a1 + 64) = 1i64;
  memset(v5, 0, sizeof(v5));
  return result;
}
```

This is IDA output - I assume that Ghidra's would be similar. `SymCryptRngAesDf` is the `df` function that you mention probably.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I could not even find the first import in Ghidra, because in the Entry function of advapi32.dll it says `bVar1 = (**(code **)(puVar3 + -2))(param_1,param_2,param_3);` and I had no idea which function this referred to.

Comment: Wouldn't reseed only be called when the PRNG is reseeded? That should happen not nearly as often as calling the buffer. So then the buffer might be at a different place than inside SymCryptRngAesReseed.

Comment: So basically, the call to the buffer could be anywhere along the flow that you specified…

Comment: Some version of SymCrypt is open source at https://github.com/microsoft/SymCrypt. Please read the documentation. Also as I mentioned `g_AesStatesTable`/`g_rootAesRngState` are responsible to maintain state - you should look into those.